# Nuxt Generate & Start command ruins VueSlickCarousel components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, slick.js, vue-ssr

When i run the command to deploy my nuxt app. The VueSlickCarousel Component plugin i use to for my slider is not rendering the default vue-slick-carousel.css even though i include it in the global css array in the nuxt.config.js, does anyone know why this is happening and how to resolve it?

```
 css: [
    '~/assets/scss/main.scss',
    'vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel.css',
    'vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel-theme.css'
  ],
```

Comment: have you create your own nuxt pluging ? (eg.  `plugins: [{ src: './plugins/vue-slick-carousel.js' }],`)

Comment: Yes i did `import Vue from 'vue' import VueSlickCarousel from 'vue-slick-carousel' Vue.component('VueSlickCarousel', VueSlickCarousel)`